# Chronos scheduler, deploy on every nodes

Tags: linux, docker, constraints, mesos

I want to deploy a Docker container using chronos, is there a way using `CONSTRAINTS` to tell him to deploy on every node ?

Comment: Contraints in Chronos appears to be a work in progress (See: https://github.com/mesos/chronos/issues/256) documented here: https://mesos.github.io/chronos/docs/api.html#constraints

Comment: That link says that some feature have been released and are documented. However, I have an attribute `company` on each nodes, it still deploy to one node. Maybe I should play with the retries but I am not sure the best way to do it.